# Defining complete Object with in One Interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have following Object in typescript.

```
export class test{
     recordname: string;
     comments: [{
         comment: string
      }]
}
```

I want to define it using Interface with in one interface. I can do it in multiple interface like this

```
export interface IComments{
      comments: string
  }
 export interface ITest{
     recordname: string;
     comments: [IComments];
 }
```

I dont want to use the approach given above I want to do it within one interface something like this

```
export interface ITest{
    recordname: string
    comments : [{
        comment: sring
     }]
   }
```

When I try to do above way it gives error. Please let me know how I can define that object with in one interface.
Thanks

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Well I checked now for what error it was giving. That error has disappeared. Must be something else that took little time to clear. Thanks for asking the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error it was giving disappeared itself later. I believe it was something else that took little time to clear.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example you are expecting

```
export interface ITest {
  recordname: string;
  comments: {
    comment: string
  }[];
}
```

Though, the good way is to use like below.

```
export interface IComments {
  comment: string
}
export interface ITest{
  recordname: string;
  comments: IComments[];
}
```